# Play local sound with audio_manager flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have following data of mp3:

data/user/0/com.hello.man/app_flutter/Hello All.mp3

Now How can I play it using the audio_manager library?

If I send it like this it doesnot play.

```
 AudioManager.instance
    .start(
    "data/user/0/com.hello.man/app_flutter/Hello All.mp3",
    
    widget.title,
    desc: widget.desc,
    // cover: "network cover image resource"
    cover: "assets/logo.png")
    .then((err) {
  print(err);
});
```

I also tried this but it failed too:

```
 AudioManager.instance
    .start(
    "file://data/user/0/com.hello.man/app_flutter/Hello All.mp3",
    widget.title,
    desc: widget.desc,
    // cover: "network cover image resource"
    cover: "assets/logo.png")
    .then((err) {
  print(err);
});
```

So how can I do that?

audio_manager source: [link](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_manager)

I also read the example but is not able to understand how actually you play the sound stored on device?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move your mp3 file into your `assets` folder in your project.

then in your `pubspec.yaml` add the path

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - Hello All.mp3
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

then you can do

```
 AudioManager.instance
    .start(
    "assets/Hello All.mp3",
    
    widget.title,
    desc: widget.desc,
    cover: "assets/logo.png")
    .then((err) {
  print(err);
});
```

Comment: I know I can play from assets folder but the audio is downloaded by the user in their own storage and the path is saved and obtained from sqflite. So I have to play from that path only.